# Parsing macOS plist values

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting, plist

I have a plist files located under /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/default/users.Am able to read the values within the plist using plutil .

```
plutil -p /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/default/users/swastibhushandeb.plist
```

Excerpt of the output:

```
{
"hint" => [
    0 => "abcxyz"
  ]
  "home" => [
    0 => "/Users/swastibhushandeb"
"name" => [
    0 => "swastibhushandeb"
    1 => "swasti.bhushan@xyz.com"
  ]
  "passwd" => [
    0 => "********"
  ]
  "picture" => [
    0 => "/Library/User Pictures/Animals/Parrot.tif"
  ]
  "realname" => [
    0 => "Swasti Bhushan Deb"
  ]
  "record_daemon_version" => [
    0 => "48400XX"
  ]
 "uid" => [
    0 => "501"

}
```

What would be the best way to select specific values (such as "name","realname" etc) from the plist using bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the `defaults` command (note that ".plist" is omitted from the filename):

```
defaults read /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/default/users/swastibhushandeb name
```

Or `PlistBuddy`:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print name" /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/default/users/swastibhushandeb.plist
```

But since this is actually a user record you're trying to read, I'd recommend using `dscl` instead:

```
dscl /Search -read /Users/swastibhushandeb name
```

Naturally, all of these use different output formats...

Comment: it works. I used the following:                                                                                                 for key in name realname uid; do defaults read /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/default/users/swastibhushandeb  $key; done|awk '{print $1}'|grep -v -e ")" -e "("

Comment: Anything that returns json?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic Not that I know of; you'll have to create the json yourself; use `jq` or something similar.